# Error: The src/environments/environment.tsng update @angular/cli path in file replacements does not exist

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I just update Angular 5.2 to Angular 6. and then I ran `ng generate universal --client-project my_project`

Now I am not able to do `ng build --prod`, however I am able to run `ng serve`. I get following error

> Error: The src/environments/environment.tsng update @angular/cli path
>   in file replacements does not exist.

I don't have anything in src/environments/environment.tsng file.

Angular Json is follows:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "my_project": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/browser",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.ico"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/assets/sass/paper-kit.scss",
              "src/assets/css/demo.css",
              "src/assets/css/nucleo-icons.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js",
              "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "dev": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.tsng update @angular/cli",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "production": {
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.tsng update @angular/cli",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "my_project:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "dev": {
              "browserTarget": "my_project:build:dev"
            },
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "my_project:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "my_project:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "karmaConfig": "./karma.conf.js",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js",
              "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/assets/sass/paper-kit.scss",
              "src/assets/css/demo.css",
              "src/assets/css/nucleo-icons.css"
            ],
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.ico"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": []
          }
        },
        "server": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/my-project-server",
            "main": "src/main.server.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.server.json"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "my_project-e2e": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "e2e",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "./protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "my_project:serve"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
            ],
            "exclude": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "my_project",
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "prefix": "app",
      "styleext": "scss"
    },
    "@schematics/angular:directive": {
      "prefix": "app"
    }
  }
}
```

package.json file is as follows

```
{
  "name": "my_app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "build:server:prod": "ng run brestCancer:server && webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors",
    "build:browser:prod": "ng build --prod",
    "build:prod": " npm run build:server:prod && npm run build:browser:prod ",
    "server": "node local.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "6.0.5",
    "@angular/common": "6.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "6.0.5",
    "@angular/core": "6.0.5",
    "@angular/forms": "6.0.5",
    "@angular/http": "6.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "6.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-server": "6.0.5",
    "@angular/router": "6.0.5",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.4",
    "@ng-toolkit/universal": "^1.1.21",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^6.0.0",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0-beta",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "cors": "~2.8.4",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "ng2-nouislider": "1.6.1",
    "nouislider": "9.2.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.12.3",
    "rxjs": "^6.2.1",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.2.1",
    "ts-loader": "4.2.0",
    "webpack": "^4.10.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.1.4",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "6.0.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "6.0.5",
    "@angular/language-service": "6.0.5",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.45",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "^2.0.3",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^5.3.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.0.4",
    "tslint": "~5.3.2",
    "typescript": "2.7.2",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.8"
  }
}
```

Comment: The error message is quite explicit... Look at that line in your`angular.json` file: `"replace": "src/environments/environment.tsng update @angular/cli",` Probably a command line pasted in the wrong place

Comment: That was it, Thanks David